# Using tlmgr inside a Linux nspawn container

Tags: texlive, linux, tlmgr

I am trying to install TeXLive into a Linux chroot environment using a systemd nspawn container. The installation seems to go fine. I am installing from a local repository using a custom profile to a chroot mounted on `/mnt`, so the installation looks like

```
systemd-nspawn -D /mnt /TeXLive/TeXLive/install-tl -repository /TeXLive/Repo -profile /TeXLive/TeXLive.profile
```

where the TeXLive installation media, repository and profile are all available inside the chroot. After installing I change the repo

```
systemd-nspawn -D /mnt/ /usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr option repository ctan
```

which seems to work. Then I try and update TexLive

```
# systemd-nspawn -D /mnt/ /usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --self

cannot contact mirror.ctan.org, returning a backbone server!
Redirecting output to 'wget-log.3'.
Redirecting output to 'wget-log.4'.
Redirecting output to 'wget-log.5'.
/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr: checksum error when downloading /tmp/EcXOu1yq0U/aFDhjBOWTO from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb: digest disagree
```

and something goes wrong. If I just use a regular chroot

```
chroot /mnt/ /usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --self
```

everything works fine. Is it possible to use tlmgr to do updates in a systemd-nspawn container?

Comment: Sounds like network issues since contacting the ctan mirror didn't work out. Are you sure networking is enabled for this container?

Comment: @norbert thanks for the lead. It looks like if choose an actual mirror it might work. Need to test some more.